# Weighted independent t-test

Tags: t-test, weights

Do you think the following approach is valid in terms of computing independent t-tests that account for statistical weights?

Essentially, we want to compare whether a random sample of people from 31 European countries in 2005 (group1) are statistically different from another random sample of people from the same 31 European countries in 2015 (group2). The thing we're measuring is responses to a question (going from 1 to 7) and that we need to weight for representativeness. By representativeness we want to make sure that the means compared in the t-tests are weighted by weights provided in the survey.

```
def weighted_ttest(group1, group2, weight1, weight2):
    mean1 = np.average(group1, weights=weight1)
    mean2 = np.average(group2, weights=weight2)
    std1 = np.sqrt(np.average((group1 - mean1)**2, weights=weight1))
    std2 = np.sqrt(np.average((group2 - mean2)**2, weights=weight2))
    n1 = len(group1)
    n2 = len(group2)

    pooled_std = np.sqrt(((n1 - 1) * std1**2 + (n2 - 1) * std2**2) / (n1 + n2 - 2))
    t_stat = (mean1 - mean2) / (pooled_std * np.sqrt(1/n1 + 1/n2))
    df = n1 + n2 - 2

    return t_stat, df


t_test_results = {}
for country in countries_with_both_years:
    data_2005 = filtered_data[(filtered_data['country'] == country) & (filtered_data['year'] == 2005)]
    data_2015 = filtered_data[(filtered_data['country'] == country) & (filtered_data['year'] == 2015)]

    t_stat, df = weighted_ttest(data_2005['Q 49a - Does your job involve working at very high speed?'],
                                data_2015['Q 49a - Does your job involve working at very high speed?'],
                                data_2005['w4'],
                                data_2015['w4'])
    p_value = ttest_ind(data_2005['Q 49a - Does your job involve working at very high speed?'],
                        data_2015['Q 49a - Does your job involve working at very high speed?'],
                        equal_var=False).pvalue  # p-value calculated using independent t-test

    t_test_results[country] = (t_stat, df, p_value)


for country, (t_stat, df, p_value) in t_test_results.items():
    print(f"{country}: t-statistic = {t_stat}, degrees of freedom = {df}, p-value = {p_value}")
```

Comment: It depends on what sort of statistical weights they are

Comment: Could you explain what "weight for representativeness" might mean?  Your description is confusing because it's unusual for *countries* to respond to questionnaires, suggesting you might have some kind of complex sample of *people* from various countries.  Details of the sampling procedure are essential for approaching problems like this.

Comment: It's getting clearer, but you still need to explain what "weights provided in the survey" mean.

Answer (score 4):

You're treating the weights in the way that you'd treat **precision** weights (as in traditional weighted least squares). Your uncertainty calculation assumes that observations with higher weights have lower uncertainty; that an observation with a weight of 2 has half the variance of an observation with a weight of 1.

That might be what you want, if, for example, the weights tell you how many people's data went into each data point.

On the other hand, you might have **sampling** weights, where the weights tell you how many people in the population each person in the data set is representing. That's different from precision weights because having 1 person   chosen randomly to represent 100 is different from having 1 observation that's an average of 100 people's data.

If you have sampling weights then the weighted means are still calculated the same way, but the denominator of the t-statistic isn't.  Your calculation will not be *horribly* wrong, but it won't be right, either.

Firstly, you don't want the pooled variance, because there's no reason to assume there's a common variance for it to estimate.  You want something more like the Satterthwaite-Welch unequal-variance t-test, so the denominator variance is $$s^2_1/n_1+s^2/n_2$$, where the $s^2$ are your weighted mean squares, rather than the pooled thing.

If you only have sampling weights and your survey doesn't have clusters or strata you are now ok; you are effectively using a model-robust sandwich estimator and that works fine with sampling weights.

If your survey has clusters or strata you really do need proper software: the `svyttest` function in the R `survey` package does it, or there might well be python code out there that explicitly says it uses sampling weights.

(What people were hoping for in the comments was some indication as to whether you had sampling weights or precision weights)

Comment: This is extremely useful, omg, thank you so much!!!